# Date Time Zone is having issue with finding ID for the location "America/Punta_Arenas"

Tags: java, date, timezone, jodatime, google-location-services

I am getting an exception while trying to get time zone for the location "America/Punta_Arenas". I am using joda LocalDateTime.

```
import org.joda.time.{DateTime, DateTimeZone}
val timezone = DateTimeZone.forID("America/Punta_Arenas")
```

So the above statement is throwing the following exception

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The datetime zone id 'America/Punta_Arenas' is not recognised
```

Is there any way I can get the time zone for the location **America/Punta_Arenas**? any help is appreciated.

Comment: I cannot reproduce. I use Joda-Time 2.9.9 on Java 1.8.0_131. Your code creates a `DateTimeZone` object that in turn prints as `America/Punta_Arenas`. What version of Joda-Time and what version of Java are you using? Also works on Java 1.7.0_79.

Comment: According to [Joda-Time Available Time Zones](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/timezones.html) America/Punta_Arenas was previously not included. There’s a procedure for [Updating the time zone data](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/tz_update.html). If that were me, I’d first try updating to that latest Joda-Time version. If that doesn’t help, I’d try updating the time zone data following the procedure.

Comment: Thank you @OleV.V. I was using an older version 2.8.1, now I updated that to 2.9.4 and issue got resolved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Joda-Time

Joda-Time carries its own copy of the time zone data known as [*tzdata*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database). Time zone definitions change, so this file may need updating.

You haven't mentioned which version of Joda-Time you are using, first upgrade to latest if possible and that should work:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/joda-time/joda-time -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
    <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.1</version>
</dependency>
```

## java.time

The Joda-Time project is now in maintenance-mode. It’s creator, Stephen Colebourne, went on to lead JSR 310 and its implementation, *java.time*, found in Java 8 and later. This is the official successor to Joda-Time.

In Java's `java.time` package you will find **ZoneId.of**.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of("America/Punta_Arenas");
```

## ThreeTen-Backport

Much of *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in the *ThreeTen-Backport* project, another project led by Stephen Colebourne.

There you will find the `org.threeten.bp.ZoneId` class.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.threeten/threetenbp -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.threeten</groupId>
    <artifactId>threetenbp</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.8</version>
</dependency>
```

The code will be the same as above with different import:

```
import org.threeten.bp.ZoneId;
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of("America/Punta_Arenas");
```

Hope that helps

Comment: I was using 2.8.1. Issue got resolved when I updated to 2.9.4. Thank you for your quick response.

Comment: No problem, glad it helped

Comment: FYI, you will also find the *tzdata* in your host operating systems, database engines such as *Postgres*, and various software libraries. All need to be updated if any time zone you care about has changed.

Comment: Thanks @BasilBourque appreciate your input.